# Date Format not showing right in generated PDFs

Tags: php, date, pdf, format

I cannot offer much details on my Problem yet, As i do not know where to start. I am not a Programmer.

Over Night I ran into a problem with my shop. All generated PDF files show a wrong date format. Like `08&period;03&period;2016` That's how it is also displayed in the html source code of my site (its UTF-8!) but the browser shows it right. My Dates come from a timestamp in MySQL and are formatted like this: `{$event_date|date_format:"%e. %B %Y"}` PDFs are created with (http://www.tcpdf.org) (TCPDF)

Now I have no clue where to start my search. Any Ideas? (I am on a managed server, I didn't do any changes to the system so may be the server environment changed. What could cause such a behavior?)

Comment: What program are the PDFs generated by, in which language?

Comment: http://www.tcpdf.org (TCPDF) is used. The problem also comes up when sharing a page (with date in text/headline) from my shop to Facebook. I have never seen that before.

Comment: I assume that @Pekka웃 actually expected *PHP* as an answer. Might be helpful if you added `php` and `tcpdf` as tags, and remove `date` and `format`, because that is just too generic.

Comment: I think that I have solved it. I found that in my smarty code: `return htmlentities(strftime($format, $timestamp), UTF-8);`
It worked well for 5 years until last week. I have now skipped the htmlentities and it seems to run. Hopefully it doesnt break something anywhere else on the site.

Comment: Your server may have had a PHP update that changed the behaviour of `htmlspecialchars()` - namely, that added periods to the list of characters that can/should be converted to a HTML entity. 


Replacing `htmlentities` with `htmlspecialchars` *might* be a good solution, giving you the safety possibly intended, without the weird behaviour, but then I don't know why TCPDF does this in the first place, so I can't say for sur.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Pekka웃! I will look into it.